# Missing hard drive partitions after installing ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I had ubuntu 13.04 and I updated it to 14.04 which faced me to much many problems. So after a while I decided to come back to 13.04. During the new installation it alarmed me that there is another OS (ubuntu 14.04) and I chose a the first choice (to delete it and install new OS).
Now, after installation, I can't find my old partitions, as if the whole hard disk is integrated. Does it mean that all of my data in hard disk has deleted? or maybe there is a way to mount the former drives?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you chose the option delete everything and install Ubuntu then I'm afraid you've deleted everything on your hard disk and made it into a single partition with Ubuntu.

A very simple test is to see the size of the new Ubuntu only partition.

Or on the command line do    fdisk -l    and look at the output.